# How to create a TfrxChartView in code?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I'm using Fast Reports 4.13.1. I need to display a number of charts on my summary band, and I'm trying to dynamically create them in `OnBeforePrint` event handler of the band. The problem is, while the charts are created correctly, the series don't show the data I'm adding to them. Here's my `OnBeforePrint` event:

```
var
  dsSections,
  dsTests,
  dsHistory: TfrxDataSet;

  Chart: TfrxChartView;
  ChartCount: Integer;                                               
begin
  dsSections := Report.GetDataSet('frdTestSections');
  dsTests := Report.GetDataSet('frdResults');
  dsHistory := Report.GetDataSet('frdTestHistory');

  ChartCount := 0;
  dsSections.First;
  while not dsSections.Eof do
  begin
    dsTests.First;
    while not dsTests.Eof do
    begin
      if dsHistory.RecordCount > 0 then
      begin
        Chart := TfrxChartView.Create(rsHistory);
        Chart.Left := (ChartCount mod 2) * 8 + 1;
        Chart.Top := (ChartCount div 2) * 5 + 0.5;

        Chart.Width := 8;
        Chart.Height := 5;
        Chart.Chart.Title.Text.Text := dsTests.Value('Name');
        Chart.Chart.View3D := False;

        Chart.AddSeries(csLine);
        dsHistory.First;
        while not dsHistory.Eof do
        begin
          ShowMessage(dsTests.Value('Name') + #13#10 + IntToStr(dsHistory.RecNo + 1) + ' ' +dsHistory.Value('Result')); // this is for debugging only
          Chart.Series[0].Add(dsHistory.Value('Result'), IntToStr(dsHistory.RecNo + 1), clBlue);                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          dsHistory.Next;
        end;                                                                                                       

        Inc(ChartCount);                                          
      end;
      dsTests.Next;
    end;
    dsSections.Next;
  end;                  
end;
```

What am I missing? Is there any property of `TfrxChartView` I should set that I'm ommiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might use XValues and YValues of SeriesData instead of *Chart.Series[0].Add*

```
//.....
  while not dsHistory.Eof do
  begin
    Chart.SeriesData[0].XValues := Chart.SeriesData[0].XValues + IntToStr(dsHistory.RecNo + 1) + ';';
    Chart.SeriesData[0].YValues := Chart.SeriesData[0].YValues + FloatToStr(dsHistory.Value('Result')) + ';';
    dsHistory.Next;
  end;

//.....
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is missing some setup right after creating `Series[0]`:

- its `Datatype` property, to establish whether its data comes from `dtDBData`, `dtBandData` or `dtFixedData`.

  - if it's *dtDBData*, then you should set its `DataSet` property
  - if it's dtBandData, then you should set its `DataBand` property
- its `XSource` and `YSource` properties
- and finally, its `Active` property